# phalcon добавить роутинг

Tags: phalcon

Подскажите. На данный момент Роутинг работает по принципу /контроллер/действие/параметры
Хочу добавить свой роутинг. Вот index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);


use Phalcon\Exception;
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Url;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql;

use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/app');
// ...

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        APP_PATH . '/controllers/',
        APP_PATH . '/models/',
    ]
    );

$loader->register();

// Create a DI
$container = new FactoryDefault();

$container->set(
    'view',
    function () {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . '/views/');
        
        return $view;
    }
);


$container->set(
    'url',
    function () {
        $url = new Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        
        return $url;
    }
);

$container->set(
    'db',
    function () {
        return new Mysql(
            [
                'host'     => '192.168.1.112',
                'username' => 'admin',
                'password' => 'admin',
                'dbname'   => 'phalcon_forum',
            ]
            );
    }
    );


$container->set(
    'Router',
    function () {
        // Create the router
        $router = new Router();
        
        // Define a route
        $router->add(
            '/posts',
            [
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'posts',
            ]
            );
        
        return $router;
    }
    );


$application = new Application($container);

try {
    // Handle the request
    $response = $application->handle(
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
        );
    
    $response->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ', $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

при переходе по http://localhost/posts

`Exception: PostsController handler class cannot be loaded`
Что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

Сработало следующее

```
$container->set(
    'router',
    function(){
        $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);
        $router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
        
        $router->add('/posts',
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' =>'posts'
                
            ));
        
        return $router;
    });
```